# How to check rails params hash from url query parameter contains double quoted string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a GET endpoint to serve an API using rails. I want to be able to check for when the user passes double quotes for the query parameter in the url.

So for example the user could call the below endpoint by passing the query parameter with double quotes or no quotes. My application is expected to behave differently if the double quotes are found in the query params..

```
localhost:8080/company/data.json?q="America Online in UK"&size=10
```

Now the user can also call the endpoint with no double quotes like this:

```
localhost:8080/company/data.json?q=America+Online+in+UK&size=10
```

OR

```
localhost:8080/company/data.json?q=AOL&size=10
```

How do I handle the above use-cases in a rails controller with respect to spaces and double quotes?

Comment: `if params[:q][0,1] == '"' && params[:q][-1,1] == '"' #do quote thing else #do other thing`?

Comment: hmm, but by the time it gets into the params hash, isn't the quotes encoded or eliminated? What exactly does the params hash contain when the endpoint is hit?

Comment: @user2081579 the best way to find out is to try. Anyway, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `request.fullpath`. Also, the content of `params[:q]` should change to show the escaped characters:

```
http://localhost:3000/?q=hello

request.fullpath
# => "/?q=hello"
params[:q]
# => "hello"



http://localhost:3000/?q=hello+world

request.fullpath
# => "/?q=hello+world"
params[:q]
# => "hello world"



http://localhost:3000/?q="hello world"

request.fullpath
# => "/?q=%22hello%20world%22"
params[:q]
# => "\"hello world\""
```

#### Further answer as requested in comment:

```
require "uri" # not required inside Rails

raw = "/?q=%22hello%20world%22"
clean = URI.unescape(raw)
# => "/?q=\"hello world\""

pattern = /\A\/\?q\=\"(.*)\"\z/
clean.match(pattern)[1]
# => "hello world"
```

#### A more practical method:

```
def query
  if (q = params[:q]).present? && with_quotes?(q)
    q.gsub("\"", "")
  end
end


def with_quotes?(string)
  string =~ /\A\"/
end
```

Comment: thank you. How would i extract just the string from the final double quotes example after checking params[:q] contains "\"?

Comment: thanks. But I get an error: `clean.match(pattern)[1] NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: That's because there is no match. My example was just that: an example. you need to expand the code, read the docs, and restructure it to make it safe for any kind of input.

Comment: All I need is to be able to check whether the variable contains a string literal. `with_quotes?("hello")` returns nothing. Where as `with_quotes?("\"which one is your fav?\"")` returns a 0. Not sure what to do with this. Should I check for where the call to with_quotes? is equal to 0?

Comment: I have the feeling that you're not very familiar with Ruby. The `with_quotes?` method works for what you need to do. Check [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-3D-7E), and you'll see why it returns `0`. And remember than in Ruby everything evaluates to `true`, with the exception of `false` and `nil`.